# CSS - Android browsers scrolling too much

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

so I made this tiny little page. [www.farley.cz](http://www.farley.cz)
It's using jQuery's load function to switch content in div. That's the whole functionality.

Now, the idea is that this containing div is in the middle of the screen. I've used the negative margin method.

```css
#mydiv {
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 880px;
    height: 476px;
    margin-top: -238px;
    margin-left: -440px;
}
```

I'm happy how it looks on desktop, but on Andoid, it behaves strangely. I'm experiencing scroll drifts (link highlight drawn outside of image), strange little jumps as I'm zooming in and zooming out. ...and when I flip the phone horizontally, the div scrolls down out of the picture.

is there away to fix this? Or should I find a better method for such a centering?

Kind regards,
Martin.

Comment: Thanks for the typo edit! It seems like Iˇve found out how to fix this. For some reason I've been ignoring position: absolute. So good so far.